# query to find all docs that match with exact terms with all the fields in the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple doc structure as follows.

```
{
    "did" : "1",
    "uid" : "user1",
    "mid" : "pc-linux1",
    "path" : "/tmp/path1" 
}
```

I need to query elastic ,that matches all fields exactly

```
GET index2/_search
{
  "query": {
     "bool":{
      "must": [
        {
          "term" : { "uid" : "user1"}
        },
        {
          "term" : { "mid" : "pc-linux1"}
        },
        {
          "term" : { "did" : "1"}
        },
        {
          "term" : { "path" : "/tmp/path1"}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The matching should happen without any kind of elastic 'analysis' on keywords, so that "/tmp/path1" is matched as a full term.

I tried to use a custom mapping: with

> "index" : false

which does not work.

```
PUT /index2?include_type_name=true
{
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc": {
      "properties" : {
        "did" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "mid" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "path" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "uid" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using elastic7.0 and few posts suggesting a custom mapping with

> "index" : "not_analysed"

does not get accepted as a valid mapping in elastic 7.0

Any suggestions?

Comment: your query seems fine. try to update your mapping with type as 'keyword' for all the fields.

Comment: its already mapped with type as 'keyword'. Mapping shown above.

Comment: no the type is text

Comment: @dn_c Yes. I was mistakenly considering the type:keyword within the "keyword" object. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match exact terms, try this query:

```
GET index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "uid": "user1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "mid": "pc-linux1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "did": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "path": "/tmp/path1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works most of the times, but one case i found this is returning more results than required. e.g docs: {
          "uid" : "user",
          "did" : "4444",
          "mid" : "pc-linux4444",
          "path" : "/tmp/path5555"
}
{
          "uid" : "user",
          "did" : "4444",
          "mid" : "pc-linux4444",
          "path" : "/tmp/path4444"
}
when queried as:
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"uid":"user"}},{"match":{"mid":"pc-linux4444"}},{"match":{"did":"4444"}},{"match":{"path":"/tmp/path5555"}}]}}}
returns both the above docs as result.

Comment: This is not an issue with this query. you need to set `path` as keyword in elasticsearch mapping. otherwise it will split from forward slash and find many matches. mapping should be like this. `"properties": {
    "path": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
 }`

Comment: i found a way without modifying the mappings. Using "path.keyword" : "/tmp/path1" in the query fields, would treat the value as a keyword just for that search query. i.e adding ".keyword" to any key of a field would treat the value as a keyword even if it defaults to "text" type in the default mapping that elastic provides. Which i think is the best solution. Thanks for the help everyone.